# How to implement has_many :through relationship in rails with this example

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

i've been searching through similar questions but i still don't get how implement this relationship. I have of course three models :

```
class Recetum < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :desc, :duration, :prep, :photo, :topic_id
    has_many :manifests
    has_many :ingredients, :through => :manifests
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :kcal, :name, :use, :unity
  has_many :manifests
  has_many :recetum, :through => :manifests
end


class Manifest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ingredient_id, :quantity, :receta_id
  belongs_to :recetum
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

Recetum would be a recipe (typo when scaffolding), this recipe may have one or more ingredients (already on the db). So when i create a new Recetum, i need the new recetum to be created and one record inserted in manifest for each ingredient entered by the user.

I would need some help now with views and controllers, how do i create the form for recetum with fields for the ingredients and more important what do i have to modify recetum controller.

Any suggestions or help would be very much appreciated as this part is crucial for my project, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options, and mainly they depend on what you want to do in your view. Do you want to display a set number of `max_ingredients` or do you want it to be completely dynamic? The dynamic case looks better for the user for sure, but it does make for some more complicated code.

Here is a good RailsCast which explains how to do it dynamically via JavaScript:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2

Unfortunately, not everyone runs with JavaScript enabled so you may want to consider doing it the static way.

Firstly, I don't think you need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Manifest` model. However, I do think you need it in your `Recetum` model. If you're going the static route, you'll probably want to set a `reject_if` option too.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :manifests, reject_if: :all_blank
```

Once you do this, you'll need to add `manifests_attributes` to your `attr_accessible`.

With the static route, you'll need to prebuild some of the `manifests`. In your `new` controller you'll want something like this:

```
max_ingredients.times do
  @recetum.manifests.build
end
```

In your `edit` and the error paths of your `create` and `update`, you may want:

```
(max_ingredients - @recetum.manifests.count).times do
  @recetum.manifests.build
end
```

Finally, your view will need some way to set the ingredient. I'll assume a select box for now.

```
f.fields_for :manifests do |mf|
  mf.label :ingredient_id, "Ingredient"
  mf.collection_select :ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name
```

You'll want to add some sort of formatting through a list or table probably.

Hopefully, that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Marvelous, thaks a lot! Only one more question, what does method 'build' do exactly ?

Comment: `build` is kind of like `new` for associations. It takes an attributes hash and sets the foreign key id appropriately.